# How to get a usb wifi dongle to work?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 22.04

I am having a typical linux experience:

- I have ubuntu "studio linux" 22.04 LTS but don't know what the "S" in "LTS" refers to.
- I bought a usb wifi dongle with "linux" written on the packaging(NW621), but should have known what to expect.
- I find the included pdf instructions fail to mention linux at all.
- The "drivers" are on the included CD but nowhere can I find information about what to actually do with the files. Is it supposed to be obvious?
- Then I search the internet to find enough support threads about this chipset or whatever to wallpaper my entire house but no straight forward instructions which I can understand or which actually work.
- As is always the case with linux I have little choice but to clutch at straws typing all kinds of commands I don't understand into a terminal probably making things worse. Many of the suggestions result in "command not found" errors.
- now I resort to adding yet another "duplicate" post asking how to "install" this consumer hardware device.
- meanwhile I wonder why Windows needs no information whatsoever from me while linux insists on a song and dance/wild goose chase.
  lsusb says it's a RTL88x2bu
  iwconfig says  "no wireless extensions"
  lsusb says it's a RTL88x2bu
  dkms status says  "rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.15.0-73-lowlatency, x86_64: installed" so some sort of "clone" command has done something?
  make  took a while. Is it "compiling"?
  modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-73-lowlatency

modprobe: FATAL: Module 88x2bu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-73-lowlatency

I actually bought two adapters,the other is a NM602. When plugged in it is not recognised at all.

I copied the CD's "linux" folder to the computer. It has directories: core hal include os_dep platform
and files:  rtl8822b.mk  runwpa  wlan0dhcp clean ifcfg-wlan0 Kconfig Makefile
but not one word about what these files are or what I am supposed to do with them. The file manager says some are shell scripts, some are text files and some are build files.
What I am supposed to make of it?
Am I better off asking an AI?

Comment: LTS = *Long Term Support*, ie. the S = support, which is *five* years for main Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud... and *three* years for *flavors* like Ubuntu Studio.  Non-LTS releases only get 9 months of *supported* life with regard security fixes, patches etc; with only packages from *main* getting *five* years but lower life from *universe* etc unless you enable optional *Ubuntu Pro* etc.  If you want a comparison with windows issues; use microsoft media & not media provided by your OEM maker; ie. it'll have no *drivers* for your hardware too having less support than Linux.

Comment: support means what? hardware, software, user?

Comment: Security fixes are available, *five* years applying to packages from *main* with packages from *universe* or community sourced having shorter lives (usually 3 years for LTS but some come with only 9 months; which is why Ubuntu ISOs don't have *universe* included by default needing the user to manually agree to add the reduced level of security packages to their system).  22.04 tells you it is the 2022-April release (ie. *year.month* format with 2000 being subtracted from *year*) so EOL of security fixes in repositories can be easily calculated..  9 months for non-LTS & 5 years for Ubuntu LTS

Comment: Why not read one of the many release notes or announcements; eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/04/21/ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-jellyfish-released/ which states "*Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud and Ubuntu Core. All the remaining flavours will be supported for 3 years. Additional security support is available with ESM (Extended Security Maintenance).*"  Ubuntu Studio is one of the *flavors* that has only 3 years of support for packages included on ISOs  (packages you add yourself may have shorter lives)

Comment: So "support" is a reference to software/code i.e. stuff under the hood so to speak and not a reference to some sort of process where I can get help to actually get it to work?

Comment: You've not said how far you got with documentation, ie. did you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide etc.. the 3.1 Device Recognition & Operation is where I'd look for the most advice.. as Linux support isn't based on make/model of board but the chipset on said board (not brand printed on box!).  Once you've recognized the chips its usually pretty easy using a search engine.

Comment: FYI:  Did you read the release notes on use of the *low latency* kernels, and suggestions **not** to use them if you have specific hardware issues like you appear to have.. ie. they make it more difficult, thus the inclusion of the *generic* kernels with Ubuntu Studio installs... ie. reading the documentation can save you time esp. if you have problems.  FYI:  S in support is the normal meaning as per industry standards (since the 1980s inc. from Microsoft.. You buy a dell you expect 'support' in human terms from the person you paid $s to, with Microsoft/Canonical providing the ~same level)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

The Simplecom NW621 with the Realtek RTL88x2bu chipset is now working.

I had a chat to google's Bard AI, which wasn't terribly helpful after it got confused and thought I was talking about which car I wanted to buy.
Eventually I found a github page(https://github.com/RinCat/RTL88x2BU-Linux-Driver) and with Bard's help figured out that I only needed to type in the commands under the "Manual DKMS installation" section which all completed successfully(this time). Then I rebooted.
I am still confused about why linux couldn't have done this within ten seconds of me plugging the adapter in.